# Git не видит каталог build/ после инициализации проекта

Tags: git, github

Столкнулся вот с такой ерундой.
Имеется каталог проекта со следующей структурой:

[image: Файловая структура]

После инициализации проекта (**git init**) и выполнения команды **git status -u** в консоли выводится следующая информация:
[image: Вывод консоли]

Теперь собственно вопрос, какого лешего в списке неотслеживаемых файлов нет папки ***build/*** ?! Я уже ее по разному переименовывал, все равно Git ее не видит.

Файл **.gitignore** абсолюто стерилен. Я ума не приложу, из-за чего это происходит...Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным ?

Comment: вероятно, этот каталог пустой. значит, в хранилище добавлять нечего. значит, не имеет смысла его показывать в выводе команды `status`. // собственно, просто произнесите вдумчиво фразу: «в списке неотслеживаемых **файлов** нет **каталога**» и помедитируйте над значениями выделенных слов.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, человечище !!! Ответ действительно лежал на поверхности. От этого, мне вдвойне стыдно.

Comment: Git не умеет каталоги.